# ifstream stopped working in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, ifstream

I have a C++ project that I haven't used in a year. It used to run perfectly, opening files with:

```
Matrix pmatrix;
    pmatrix.readFromFile("pmtx.txt");
```

and in the function:

```
void Matrix::readFromFile(string filename){

            ifstream tmfile;
            tmfile.open(filename.c_str());

            if (!tmfile) {
                cout << "unable to open tm file";
                //return 1;
            }

etc
}
```

It keeps telling me "unable to open tm file". I've been breaking my head about this. Obviously the file is in the directory of the src and I copied it to Debug and Release, I gave it full permissions. I use eclipse.

Any ideas why this just stopped working?

Comment: You could print your `args[0]` to get the current path of your programm.
Maybe use `tmfile.is_open()` to check if file was opend successfully

Comment: The strangest thing. If I do: cout << "path" << argv[0];
 cout.flush(); right after int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    it outputs nothing, just the file open error (not even "path"). Could this be something else?

Comment: ok, I just copied the cpp and h files to a new project and it works. No idea what happened there... a clean did not help as well. Thanks thought for letting me realise it's not just a ifstream problem.

Comment: I am not sure if `cout` can print a `char*`, please try:
`std::string s(args[0]);` and then `cout << s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something strange screwed up with the eclipse project. I created a new project, copied in existing files and it worked.

Comment: It just did it again... this is annoying!!